# Can't install ruby-debug?

Tags: ruby, ruby-debug

Has anyone else encountered this?

```
gem install ruby-debug
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I am using a gemset if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I believe the gem name for ruby 1.9 is `ruby-debug19`. Or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `debugger` gem is the de facto standard for the current version of Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The only debugger that works for me so far is the `debugger` gem found at https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Put the `gem 'debugger'` in Gemfile or install it just for development.

```
group :development do
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

I have tried a couple of other options (which all failed) before landing on `debugger` gem. Specifically, `ruby-debug` and `ruby-debug19` (https://github.com/denofevil/ruby-debug19).

`ruby-debug` failed to install. While `ruby-debug19` did install, I got an error on `require 'ruby-debug' ; Debugger.start`.

Here is my environment:

```
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [i686-linux]
Rails 3.2.11
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 32bit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ruby-debug19` version as the 'regular' version is incompatible with Ruby 1.9:

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

For more information check [the gems project page](https://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug).

Comment: ruby-debug19 isn't compatible with 1.9.3 at this time. As @jimmy_cuadra said, the "debugger" gem is the de facto standard.